# PHP SoapClient trying to consume a C# generated WSDL giving errors

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

So I'm trying to consume a WSDL generated by C# .NET application using PHP. I've ran into multiple issues and have worked my way up to this point where I cannot seem to find the next thing to do.

I'm using SOAP 1.2 to prevent the `text/xml` error from happening (`expected type application/soap+xml`), whereas SOAP 1.2 is accepted by the application as `text/xml`.

The error I receive now is:

`[message:protected] => The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/IMembership/AcquireSecurityToken'.`

I'm a little worried why it is not detected any action from my end (`''`) but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong or what I should be approaching differently.

Underneath you'll find most of the relevant code involved in trying to get this to work for now.

```
$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_2,
                "trace"=>1,
                "exceptions"=>1,
                );


$client = new SoapClient("http://removed.for.now/Membership.svc?wsdl", $params);
$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','AcquireSecurityToken', 'http://tempuri.org/IMembership/AcquireSecurityToken',true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);

$args = array("username"=>"user", "password"=>"goodpw");

try { 
    $result = $client->AcquireSecurityToken($args);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "<h1>Last request</h1>";
    // print_r the error report. Omitted for clarity.
}
```

Any tips or suggestions? Things I'm not doing right or should be trying differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of some lovely people on IRC.

The ActionHeader that I tried to add using `$actionHeader` was close, but not correct.

```
$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'Action', 'http://tempuri.org/IMembership/AcquireSecurityToken');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);
```

Did the trick.